# Converting for loops to parallel loops

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have written a code that calculates the focus value of an image. but it takes more than 5 seconds to be done.

```
 public double GetFValue(Image image)
        {
            Bitmap source = new Bitmap(image);
            int count = 0;
            double total = 0;
            double totalVariance = 0;
            double FM = 0;
             Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
             Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,source.Width,source.Height);
              Bitmap targetRect = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

            // converting to grayscale
            for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
                {
                    count++;
                    Color c = source.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int luma = (int)(c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11);
                    source.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma)); // the image is now gray scaled 
                    var pixelval = source.GetPixel(x, y);
                  //  targetRect.Save(@"C:\Users\payam\Desktop\frame-42-rectangle.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    int pixelValue = pixelval.G;
                    total += pixelValue;
                    double avg = total / count;
                    totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - avg, 2);
                    double stDV = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count); // the standard deviation, which is also the focus value
                    FM = Math.Round(stDV, 2);
                }
            }
            return FM;
        }
```

I am trying to convert this code to a Parallel computation. I end up with bugs that I can not get my head around them. Any suggestion?

```
  public double CalculateFvalue (Image image)
    {
        Bitmap myimage = new Bitmap(image);
        int count = 0;
        int total = 0;
        double totalVariance = 0;
        double FM = 0;
        Parallel.For(0, image.Height, y =>
            {

            for (int x = 0; x < myimage.Width; x++)
                   {
                           count++;
                           Color c = myimage.GetPixel(x, y);
                           int luma = (int)(c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11);
                           myimage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma)); // the image is now gray scaled 
                           var pixelval = myimage.GetPixel(x, y);
                           int pixelValue = pixelval.G;
                           total += pixelValue;
                           double avg = total / count;
                           totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - avg, 2);
                           double stDV = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count); // the standard deviation, which is also the focus value
                           FM = Math.Round(stDV, 2);
                   }


    });

        return Math.Round(FM,2);
    }
```

Comment: What are the bugs you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, you have a whole load of thread safety issues. But anyway, getpixel is very slow, look into lockbits instead

Comment: You're updating `count`, `total` and `FM` concurrently on different threads. You should have each loop iteration calculate local values for these and then combine them at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, dont try and run GetPixel in parallel, use lockBits instead.

Your code using lockbits:

```
    public double GetFValue(Image image)
    {
        Bitmap source = new Bitmap(image);
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double totalVariance = 0;
        double FM = 0;
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);
        //Bitmap targetRect = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

        //new
        ///*
        BitmapData bmd = source.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, source.PixelFormat);
        int[] pixelData = new int[(rect.Height * rect.Width) -1];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, pixelData, 0, pixelData.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.Length; i++)
        {
            count++;
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(pixelData[i]);
            int luma = (int)(c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11);
            //Probably a formula for this
            pixelData[i] = Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma).ToArgb(); 
            total += luma;
            double avg = total / count;
            totalVariance += Math.Pow(luma - avg, 2);
            double stDV = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);
            FM = Math.Round(stDV, 2);
        }
        source.UnlockBits(bmd);
        return FM;
     }
```

In a quick test using a 1024 x 768 jpg from win7 sample pictures (Chrysanthemum.jpg):

lockbits: 241 milliseconds

getPixel: 2208 milliseconds

Note when converting your code i noticed some odd things (like getpixel, setpixel, getpixel on the same pixel?) but i guess you know what you want to achieve, and this code is an exact equivalent of yours

Comment: While this is definitely good advice the same would apply to a sequential implementation. Eve's answer below is actually more pertinent to the original question. Shared state is invariably a bad idea when parallelising code.

Comment: You rock man, this worked perfectly. I am going to convert the for loop part to a parallel code and will pass my final result here. Final note, this code is measuring the focus of an image, by first converting it to gray scale and then by using standard deviation over the bitmap matrix. It is one method, there are many other methods to measure focus of an image. This is an interesting project that I am working on and will post more about it later.

Answer (score 7):

That happens because of the variables that you have declared outside of the scope of `Parallel.For`. Since their access (and writing) is non-deterministic, you might get values overwritten with the wrong data (Such as `FM`).

I suggest you to make every iteration yield information about its result, then use the collected data to manipulate your variables outside in a thread-safe way. You could also get away with it by using a few `lock` statements, but I personally would avoid that.

Comment: thanks, I am going to work on your suggestion. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: +1: Also make sure *not to* modify Bitmap without synchronization. Current code uses `SetPixel` in non-threadsafe way. (Aslo as noted earlier Get/Set pixel calls should not be used if performance is of any concern).